# Can't click on a ListView item

Tags: android, listview

I was enhancing my application going from a simple ListActivity to a more complex one, where in addition to the ListView I also have a search text and a Button.
In the simple version, when I click on the item, the listener gets it.
In the more complex one, when I click on the item, nothing happens, and in debug mode, I don't hit the listener.

In the two examples below I stripped all the unessential logic leaving just enough to recreate the problem.

Working code:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    String[] eventList =  {"Queen", "Chicago", "Kinks"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Define event list
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, R.layout.activity_main,
                        R.id.lvEventList, eventList));
    }

    // Process List Item selection
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        Context context = MainActivity.this;
        Toast.makeText(context, "item " + position + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

and the corresponding Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".EventList">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lvEventList"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="@+id/txtEventName"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Not working code

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String[] eventList =  {"Queen", "Chicago", "Kinks"};


    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Define event list
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvEventList);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_list_text,
                eventList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // Process List Item selection
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        Context context = MainActivity.this;
        Toast.makeText(context, "item " + position + " was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

and the 2 corresponding layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <!--android:background="#eef"-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">
        listView

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"
            android:layout_weight="70">
            <!--<requestFocus/>-->
        </Button>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:background="#ffffff">
        </EditText>


    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvEventList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and (copy of simple item list 1 with extensions)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"

    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contextClickable="true" />
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Your second XML has a random `listView` word above the Button... That won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListActivity` has a method named `onListItemClick` but `AppComaptActivty` doesn't have this method you should set it manually on list view

after this line

```
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

write this:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Context context = MainActivity.this;
    Toast.makeText(context, "item " + position + " was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`onListItemClick` means nothing to `AppCompatActivity`.

If you annotated your Java methods, you'd have noticed that. The compiler may even be telling you "method unused".

For example, in the first code

```
@Override // This works
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    Context context = MainActivity.this;
    Toast.makeText(context, "item " + position + " was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Put `@Override` on the second code, it wouldn't work.

---

Now, you actually can **keep** a `ListActivity` **and** use your own XML layout.

You just need to [go over the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) that says.

> if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`. To do this, your own view MUST contain a `ListView` object with the id `"@android:id/list"`

That looks like this

```
 <ListView 
   android:id="@android:id/list"  <!-- Notice the ID -->
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

If you wanted to keep using AppCompatActivity, though, you can find that ID with `findViewById(android.R.id.list)`